# Механизим анти обфускации pl/sql

Tags: oracle, plsql, обфускация

Есть ли какой нибудь способ раскрыть PL/SQL код, который подвергли обфускации?

Comment: Пример такого кода приведите.

Comment: @PinkTux эээээ просто набор символов....

Comment: Это не пример, а описание.

Comment: @PinkTux в хеадере стандартное объявление функций и процедур. В боди такая штука: create or replace package body XXX wrapped yz6XxvPpUTfY2OorySvJKzx7X2/uVi0bQs9L4uXgMkliuw4kmXN5t1FZTpT5kek65dgVXAF5
ambsBwL2kL4dmCBV7SCB+Vdzi0weJJ21fZBt/rz4sMGqSL4f/1CkuuLNdJq4aHho90POv6T4
4rtUuxC1cjlheWyqOkGBxu0SU+x9dWMK6ffDOOwp5QgRYqYyFHAu+pGjqM6XLYPy0SVWDOBj
yAWjTXFj9uJpIT5ikrEJFoOJt7g9joOOlehZGDzmpt2ecYu3Mvdy3Heb/DFjcye7HOFRlRhM
vmKnQmiH2DDOGZjQGbW8KkIe/ZpzM4y/qqX/eDtdkCCqwZAHeuXeLWhst15z5DyMxLUG7k+e
eWfNGSxp87zKiRWl9iEUX9iX1xp72LYKe9HxhKdgK6MYKsivDnznylYY

Comment: Ну гугл по запросу "oracle unwrap" что то дает, но рабочее ли оно и нет ли в нем вирусов большой вопрос ...

Comment: @Mike, есть и онлайн [варианты](http://www.codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/) :) Но то ли тут кусок неполный, то ли он не работает.

Comment: @Mike не полный :). Там очень очень много

Comment: @PinkTux Да, я увидел online, и код пакета странно смотрится, по крайней мере в старых версиях оракла там в начале шли короткие строки повторяющихся символов, в этом примере этого не заметно. и много где пишут что это невозможно

Comment: Если была бы возможность код раскрыть, а зачем его тогда вообще закрывать? Вся идея вропа, чтобы код не лежал на серваке открытым.

Comment: @0xdb тем не менее я нашел утилиту которая прекрасно развраппила мне код. В понедельник когда буду на работе я дам ответ на данный вопрос

Comment: Ждём с нетерпением.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В Oracle применяют некую "обфускацию" пакетов, применяя к ним wrapping PL/SQL кода. Но всё это бесполезно. Их очень легко разврапить. Как пример, https://codecrete.net/UnwrapIt/ - с его помощью можно легко преобразовать пакет в обычный код PL/SQL. В принципе такое "сокрытие" не приносит никаких преимуществ. Лучше не пользоваться такими средствами. По сути это есть некая "обертка" (wrapping в переводе и есть обертка), которую умные люди научились разворачивать.

Comment: Лучшке поздно чем не когда. Насколько я разобрался сам в этом вопросе там в качестве ключа используется пароль к БД.